# Not able to host react app using webpackdevserver on public ip of AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am running react app on AWS EC2 it works locally when accessed through localhost:3000

I want to make it publicaly accessible so i passed public ip into following command

```
  var webpackDevServer = new WebpackDevServer(bundler, {
    publicPath: '/',
    hot: false,
    quiet: false,
    noInfo: true,
    stats: {
        colors: true
    }
});
webpackDevServer.listen(3000, '18.230.124.435', function () {
    console.log('Bundling project, please wait...');
});
```

i am using gulp to run tasks.

i am geting an error Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 18.230.124.435:3000

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: Hey Wayneio,
Sorry man. I resolved it long time back. Don't remember now :)